# Wine не видит dll?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dll, wine

Я скачал приложение Snap Camera на Линукс и установил его через wine. Но при запуске он сообщает что Library Qt5Core,Vcruntime,Msvpc не найдены и не работает  все эти файлы или почти все лежат в этой же папке на виртуальном диске wine в папке с эти exe

Comment: разрядность не та?

Comment: не знаю. разрядность чего? где посмотреть?